# Bookmarking video or audio files in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsurl, persistent

In my application i want to bookmark audio and video playing files, Can i do that?

Can any one please tell me the approach how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to how you could implement a persistent storage pattern. Have a look at [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Example: [iPhone Programming Tutorial - Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDetaults](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults)